# Optimal Approach for Monitoring Program Status and Implementing Email Notifications Across Multiple Servers?

Tags: python, authentication, email, automation, push-notification

How to set up an email push mechanism related to program running status on multiple hosts?

What I want: an outgoing email that can be deployed on multiple hosts, with the same password or access token, so that python or other scripts can send the relevant status at the end of the run.

I tried SMTP. However, SMTP providers generally requires a separate access password for each client and needs to be generated separately on each host(I tried QQ, sina.com and 163.com), but this number is generally limited (my QQ mailbox is 5).

I want to deploy this functionality on many servers, so this approach is not very useful.

I don't have sufficient knowledge about computer networks and cloud services, so I truly appreciate your patient explanations.

I established email pushing mechanism on a single host using the following python script. (The following code was modified from `py_reminder`. For more details, see [here](https://github.com/Wenzhi-Ding/py_reminder))

```py
def send_email(task, time_start=0.0, args=None, kwargs=None, error='', to=''):
    config = {
        'SMTP': 'smtp.xxxx.com',
        'PORT': 25,
        'ADDRESS': 'xxxx@yy.com',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
    }
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(config['SMTP'], config['PORT'])
    server.login(config['ADDRESS'], config['PASSWORD'])

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = formataddr(('PyReminder', config['ADDRESS']))
    if to:
        msg['To'] = to
    else:
        msg['To'] = config['TO']

    formatted_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    time_usage = (timer() - time_start) / 60 if time_start else 0
    common = f"""Task: {task}
Time: {formatted_time}
Machine: {gethostname()}
Time Usage: {time_usage:.2f} mins
Args: {args if args else '-'}
Kwargs: {kwargs if kwargs else '-'}
Status: """

    if error:
        msg['X-Priority'] = '2'
        message = common + 'Error! Please check! \n\n%s' % error
        msg['Subject'] = '[PyReminder] Error for %s' % task
    else:
        message = common + 'Complete!'
        msg['Subject'] = '[PyReminder] Completion for %s' % task

    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
    server.sendmail(config['ADDRESS'], to, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
    del msg


def monitor(task='Your Task', to='', mute_success=False, disable=False):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            logger = logging.Logger('catch_all')
            ts = timer()
            try:
                value = func(*args, **kwargs)
                if not disable and not mute_success:
                    send_email(task=task, time_start=ts, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, error='', to=to)
                return value
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(e, exc_info=True)
                if not disable:
                    send_email(task=task, time_start=ts, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, error='%s\n%s\n%s' % sys.exc_info(),
                               to=to)

        return wrapper_decorator

    return decorator


@monitor('test', 'yyy@zzz.com')
def test():
    sleep(1)
```